# Error con Glide y Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-glide

tengo un problema para llamar a Glide desde un adapter para un fragment, logro hacerlo con una activity pero no puedo con un Fragment, alguien me puede ayudar??? Gracias hermanos.

Error:  error: cannot access Fragment

```
 Glide.with(mCtx).load(product.getDatosDeImagen()).into(objeto.imgCategoria);
```

Comment: Cual es el problema en realidad, no se muestra o marca error?

Answer (score 0):

Si te encuentras dentro de un `Fragment` puedes obtener el contexto usando `getActivity()`.

Debes solo asegurar 2 puntos:

- `product.getDatosDeImagen()` debe contener la url de una imagen o un entero que indique el id de un recurso dentro del proyecto.
- `objeto.imgCategoria` debe contener la referencia de un ImageView dentro del Fragment.

---

De esta forma cargarías la imagen dentro del `ImageView`:

```
Glide.with(getActivity()).load(product.getDatosDeImagen()).into(objeto.imgCategoria);
```